# Group Testing with limited groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, experiment-design

Consider the problem of group testing where the objective is to identify one defective item from a group of $N$ items. Assume a noisy setup where any test outputs the correct result with a given probability $p > 1/2$ and an incorrect result otherwise. We want to identify the true defective item with a probability of at least $1 - \delta$, where $\delta$ is given. This is a rather standard setup and there are various algorithms proposed in the literature that can be used to obtain the solution in $O(\log N)$ tests. However, all these algorithms assume that one can test any group of any given size. I was thinking about the case where it is not feasible to have all possible groups due to say physical, financial or any other such constraints.

We can consider a case where we are given a subset of possible groups $G \subseteq \mathcal{P}_N$ where $\mathcal{P}_N$ denotes the power set of $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. It is given that the set $G$ is rich enough to identify any one of the $N$ items if they are defective. It is clear that $|G| > \log_2 N$ should hold true.

I was wondering if there are any existing algorithms in the literature addressing such a case. In particular, the algorithm should provide a method to choose groups from the set $G$ (adaptively or non-adaptively) to identify the defective item in the least number of tests. It can be assumed that the set $G$ is known before beginning the tests, however, the algorithm should be general and independent of any specific structure in $G$. Also is it still always possible to identify the defective item in $O(\log N)$ tests for any $G$. If not, then what is the best one can achieve? Intuitively, I think it is not possible to achieve $O(\log N)$ for every $G$ and the performance should depend on $G$.

It would be really great if someone could provide a reference for the same. Thank you!